# How to copy all hive table from one Database to other Database

Tags: hive, hiveql, impala

I have default db in hive table which contains 80 tables .
I have created one more database and I want to copy all the tables from default DB to new Databases.

Is there any way I can copy from One DB to Other DB, without creating individual table.

Please let me know if any solution..
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I can think of couple of options.

1. Use CTAS.

   ```
   CREATE TABLE NEWDB.NEW_TABLE1 AS select * from OLDDB.OLD_TABLE1;
   CREATE TABLE NEWDB.NEW_TABLE2 AS select * from OLDDB.OLD_TABLE2;
   ...
   ```
2. Use IMPORT feature of Hive
   https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+ImportExport

Hope this helps.

Comment: Note that `show databases` will give the 80 names that are needed, and that the 80 lines can then easily be created in a tool like excel.

Comment: No. 1 worked great for me, except the partitions don't copy over. Any way to achieve that?

Answer (score 5):

These are probably the fastest and simplest way to copy / move tables from one db to other.

**To move table** [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30586500/2341189)

Since 0.14, you can use following statement to move table from one database to another in the same metastore:

```
alter table old_database.table_a rename to new_database.table_a;
```

The above statements will also move the table data on hdfs if `table_a` is a managed table.

**To copy table**

You can always use `CREATE TABLE <new_db>.<new_table> AS SELECT * FROM <old_db>.<old_table>;` statements. But I believe this alternate method of copying database using `hdfs dfs -cp` and then creating tables with `LIKE` can be a little faster if your tables are huge:

```
hdfs dfs -cp /user/hive/warehouse/<old_database>.db /user/hive/warehouse/<new_database>.db
```

And then in Hive:

```
CREATE DATABASE <new_database>;
CREATE TABLE <new_database>.<new_table> LIKE <old_database>.<old_table>;
```

Comment: This is not a "copy" but a "move".

Comment: @ThomasDecaux My bad. Have updated the answer for copying too. Thanks.

Comment: The hdfs method would mess up the table's metadata, causing problems.

Comment: This is a nice idea, but I think it is a bit more complicated than this and does not work

Comment: Will the alter table command work well for external table also ? or it's applicable only for managed table ?

Answer (score 4):

**create external table new_db.table like old_db.table location '(path of file in hdfs file)';**

if you have partition in table then you have to add partition in new_db.table.

Comment: And how do you do that ?

Answer (score 1):

You can approach one of the following option :

The syntax looks something like this:
EXPORT TABLE table_or_partition TO hdfs_path;
IMPORT [[EXTERNAL] TABLE table_or_partition] FROM hdfs_path [LOCATION [table_location]];

Some sample statements would look like:
EXPORT TABLE  TO 'location in hdfs';

Use test_db;
IMPORT FROM 'location in hdfs';

Export Import can be appled on a partition basis as well:
EXPORT TABLE  PARTITION (loc="USA") to 'location in hdfs';

The below import commands imports to an external table instead of a managed one
IMPORT EXTERNAL TABLE FROM 'location in hdfs' LOCATION ‘/location/of/external/table’;