# Duplicate a table by changing the name of the duplicated table

Tags: sql, hive

I want to duplicate a table by changing the name of the duplicated table by adding today's date.

The date should be generated automatically (the day of the execution of the request)

Example :

Original Table Name = x

Duplicate Table Name = x_20221216 <-- today's date

Comment: CREATE TABLE  x_20221216 AS select * from x; https://stackoverflow.com/a/26638107/7130689

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create table x_20221216 as select * from x

Comment: Thank you but I want to generate the date automatically (the day of the execution of the request)

Comment: That is called "dynamic sql" and I'm not sure the best way to perform it in hive.  Typically you would have a shell script or programming language build the sql statement as a string using whatever functions are available for date formatting, then you just execute that string on the dbms.